# Flask slower in mod_wsgi than development

Tags: python, apache, flask

I have a barebone flask like this:

```
# run.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'the application is running'
```

that I deployed both in the development mode:

```
nohup flask run --host=0.0.0.0 &
```

And also deployed in the production environment using wsgi with the alis myflask using virtualenv, and here is my wsgi file:

```
# flask.wsgi
import os
import sys
activate_this = '/usr/local/myflask/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '../..'))
sys.path.append('/usr/local/myflask/')
from myflask.run import app as application

# /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/myflask.conf
WSGIScriptAlias /myflask /usr/local/myflask/wsgi/flask.wsgi
WSGIScriptReloading On

<Directory /usr/local/myflask/wsgi>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

However, I did a benchmark using Apache Bench command and realized the performance of Apache server is way worse than the built in development server of flask? can anyone explain to me is this what is supposed to be?

Here is the result:

```
# wsgi apache
ab -c 100 -n 10000 http://54.175.125.11/myflask
> Time taken for tests:   12.805 seconds
# develop
ab -c 100 -n 10000 http://54.175.125.11:5000/
> Time taken for tests:   7.779 seconds
```

What is going on ?!

Comment: You need to share more of your apache configuration. How is your apache mpm configured? Are you using prefork, worker, event? What's the number of threads and/or processes?

Comment: @Boris, I used all the default apache2 configurations and did not touch anything. Looks like i need to get into the journey of "fine tuning"?

Comment: Yeah, that would my first instinct. You may also take a look at mod wsgi configuration params. This page will have some explanations http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/mod_wsgi/